# SSIS Lookup Returns Too Much Data

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that performs a lookup on a table with tens of millions of rows. It seems by default it returns all rows from the table into a refTable, and then selects from that refTable where the columns match specified parameters to find the matching lookup. Does it have to insert into a refTable to do this? Can I just filter out with the parameters immediately? Currently it is pulling the millions of records into the refTable and it is wasting a ton of time. Is it done this way because multiple records are being looked up from that refTable, or is it pulling all of those records every time for each lookup it tries to find?

Here is the slow way and my proposed new way of doing this:

```
-- old
select * from (SELECT InvoiceID, CustomerId, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate
 FROM Invoice) [refTable]
where [refTable].[InvoiceNumber] = ? and [refTable].[CustomerId] = ? and [refTable].[InvoiceDate] = ?

-- new
SELECT i.InvoiceID, i.CustomerId, i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceDate
 
 FROM Invoice i
where i.InvoiceNumber = ? and i.CustomerId = ? and i.InvoiceDate = ?
```

Comment: Do you use the Lookup from SSIS? If so, what cache mode do you use?

Comment: @raphi5430 Partial Cache mode. Are the records pulled back to refTable because it uses those same records for each row it's trying to lookup? Or is it creating the massive refTable every time the lookup is performed? For example I'm processing an XML file with multiple invoices. Is it building that massive refTable every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Partial Cache Mode makes a new call to the database every time it encounters a new distinct value in the source data. Afterwards it chaches this new value. It's not creating a massiv ref table.
The two queries

```
Select * FROM A WHERE A.Id = ?

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A) [refTable] WHERE refTable.Id = ?
```

have the same execution plan. So there is no difference

Overview over the different caching modes:
[Overview over caching modes](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2019/09/05/ssis-lookup-cache-modes/)

You can speed the whole thing up by not using a whole table as Lookup Connection but a sql query which returns only the columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had one lookup that was a full cache instead of partial cache like the others, it was loading nearly a million rows so it slowed things up quite a bit. I have a good index created so doing the lookup for each source item isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another good method is for handling lookup is this -> [Lookup Pattern: Cascading](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/lookup-pattern-cascading/ba-p/387503).

Use a full cache lookup for values that where created yesterday and partial cache for anything older. 80-20 rule, 80% of the rows should hit the full cache and fly through.